# How to find Magento 1.x edition (community, enterprise or .go)

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

How to find magento(in magento version 1) edition(community or enterprise or .GO)

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1 just open the next file `app/Mage.php` and check `$_currentEdition` variable value:

```
$ cat YOUR_MAGENTO_ROOT/app/Mage.php | grep _currentEdition
```

or simply dive inside source code:

```
... 

static private $_isInstalled;

/**
 * Magento edition constants
 */
const EDITION_COMMUNITY    = 'Community';
const EDITION_ENTERPRISE   = 'Enterprise';
const EDITION_PROFESSIONAL = 'Professional';
const EDITION_GO           = 'Go';

/**
 * Current Magento edition.
 *
 * @var string
 * @static
 */
static private $_currentEdition = self::EDITION_COMMUNITY;

/**
 * Gets the current Magento version string
 * @link http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/new-community-edition-release-process/
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function getVersion()
{
    $i = self::getVersionInfo();
    return trim("{$i['major']}.{$i['minor']}.{$i['revision']}" . ($i['patch'] != '' ? ".{$i['patch']}" : "")
                    . "-{$i['stability']}{$i['number']}", '.-');
}

...
```

Happy coding ;)